# Creating a constructor for polynomials with an unknown amount of terms?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm making a program that can differentiate different functions. Right now I'm looking to differentiate polynomials with an unknown amount of terms. Is it possible to make a constructor for the polynomials, when the amount of terms they will contain changes from one polynomial to the other?

Comment: Give us some input and output of your thought process

Comment: You could introduce a class `Monomial` which has fields for factor and exponent (or degree). Then, the `Polynomial` is a collection of `Monomials`. Make sure that Monomials of the same degree are merged together.